# Google visualization dashboard with map

Tags: google-maps, google-visualization, dashboard

I came across this [gist link](https://gist.github.com/battlehorse/1210987) which contains the google visualization dashboard with map. How can I customize that map by adding custom markers and info windows?

Answer (score 0):

For the infowindows this is what you'll need to look at:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

And concerning markers you'll want to look at this:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

Comment: Is it possible to include info window in the above sample?

Comment: Yes, look at the first link